# Rails 3.2 Paperclip S3 Not Loading in Localhost

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I just upgraded to Rails 3.2 and I'm using Amazon S3 with Paperclip to upload photos to my app.

Before my Image Urls would be:

```
 http://s3.amazonaws.com/dealphotos.website.com/photos/428/large/Sandisk120Drive?1334754504
```

Now my Image Urls on Localhost are:

```
 http://s3.amazonaws.com/dealphotos.website.com/deals/photos/000/000/428/large/Sandisk120Drive?1334754504
```

Notice the additional 000/000's - even if I take them out and visit the link it says:

```
 <Error>
  <Code>AccessDenied</Code>
  <Message>Access Denied</Message>
   <RequestId>"Long String of Numbers"</RequestId>
   <HostId>
    "Gives me a really long string of letters and numbers"
   </HostId>
```

My Deal Model:

```
   has_attached_file :photo, :styles => { :small =>"268x160>", :large =>"350x250>" },
          :storage => :s3, 
          :bucket => 'dealphotos.website.com',
          :s3_credentials => {
          :access_key_id => ENV['S3_KEY_SPICY'],
          :secret_access_key => ENV['S3_SECRET_SPICY']
        }
```

And the images dont show up!

Before all I had to do was pull from Heroku and all my images and files would go to my development. What's going on?

Answer (score 1):

You are most likely using the latest version of Paperclip (version >= 3).

Since this is a major version of paperclip there are documented incompatibilities with older versions of paperclip.

One MAJOR (and in my books good) change is that the default storage location of assets has changed.

Earlier it used to be /system/:attachment/:id/:style/:filename.:extension (from memory). This would be disastrous if you had 2 attachments with the same name (Company logo and Product logo) for example.

Now the new path used by paperclip is /system/:class/:attachment/:id_partition/:style/:filename.:extension

This means all your assets will be stored in the directory specified by above. :id_partitions are used so that the number of nodes (files/directories) in one directory doesnt exceed 1000.

I hope i've been able to explain the reason WHY you are seeing the problem. The default path  has changed.

You have 2 options now -

1. Move old assets into the correct place in the new directory scheme (painful but recommended).
2. Move new assets into the old directory structure and add a :url + :path option in your attachment definition in the model to continue using the older scheme. (See https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/blob/master/UPGRADING ).

Since it appears that you have images in BOTH the new structure and the old one. So no matter what you decide files will need to be moved from one structure to another. Unless the assets are bookmarked in some way, I suggest you move the older assets into the new directory structure.

Comment: If you've just updated to the new version and you dont have assets in the new directory structure, you could possibly lock your Gemfile to ~> 2.0 version of paperclip and regain old functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Check out CarrierWave gem to file uploads. It works with 3.2 without any problems ;)

http://railscasts.com/episodes/253-carrierwave-file-uploads